# Is it possible to target a <select> with a specific option selected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say I have the following HTML:

```html
<select>
    <option value="0">Closed</option>
    <option value="1">Open</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to add a border to the `<select>` that depends on the currently selected value:

- Red border when `Closed` is selected
- Green border when `Open` is selected

[image: select open closed]

**Is there a CSS selector that would target the `<select>` only when its value is `0` or `1`?**

Comment: I can;t understand what you want to achieve, can you provide an image or a fiddle

Comment: you need jQuery to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible purely in CSS, as CSS does not have any understanding of selected dropdown `option`s. (Even if it did, it would not be possible to match the `option` then go back up to the parent `select`).

As such,  JavaScript is your only option here. I can provide an example, but you didn't tag the question JavaScript so I don't know if this is an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you can do something like this

```
$(".select_box").on('change',function(){
if($(".select_box").find(":selected").text() == 'Open'){
    $(".select_box").css('border-color','green');
}
else{
    $(".select_box").css('border-color','red');
}
});
```

[the complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUtty/)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it only with CSS. Use Javascript or jQuery.
Eg:- `$('#id :selected')`