# Option selected text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML select form with several options.

I would like to modify the color of the text options but only for certain options. In my Fiddle below, I modified the color for the **Tuesday** option but the modification is only visible when scrolling the options down. 
How could I have the specific color also visible for **Tuesday** when it is selected i.e. at the top of the options?

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/280/

Code:

```css
.form-control {
  color: blue;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form action="#" id="form" method="post" data-toggle="validator" style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class="form-inline">

    <select class="form-control" name="date">
      <option value="0">
        Date
      </option>
      <option value="1">
        Monday
      </option>
      <option value="2" selected class="selected">
        Tuesday
      </option>
      <option value="3">
        Wednesday
      </option>
      <option value="4">
        Thursday
      </option>

    </select>

  </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to target a <select> with a specific option selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161425/is-it-possible-to-target-a-select-with-a-specific-option-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, where it keeps each option's individual color and set the selected (top) to the very same color.

*Update*

For some reason both Firefox and Edge/IE fail to get an `option` element's actual style, so I came up with this *dirty trick*, where a `data-color` attribute is set on both the `select` and `option` elements, and when found on an `option`, that will be used or else fall back on the default value from the `select`'s `data-color`.

```js
function selchanged(el) {
  var col = el.options[el.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-color');
  if (col) {
    el.style.color = col;
  } else {
    el.style.color = el.getAttribute('data-color');
  }
}
// run once to set on load
selchanged(document.querySelector('.form-control'))
```

```css
.form-control,
.form-control option {
  color: blue;
}
.form-control option[data-color='#090'] {
  color: #090;
}
.form-control option[data-color='#f00'] {
  color: #f00;
}
.form-control option[data-color='#00f'] {
  color: #00f;
}
.form-control option[data-color='#0ff'] {
  color: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form" method="post" data-toggle="validator" style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <select data-color="#00f" class="form-control" name="date" onchange="selchanged(this);">
      <option data-color="#090" value="0">
        Date
      </option>
      <option data-color="#090" value="1">
        Monday
      </option>
      <option data-color="#f00" value="2" selected class="selected">
        Tuesday
      </option>
      <option data-color="#0ff" value="3">
        Wednesday
      </option>
      <option data-color="#0ff" value="4">
        Thursday
      </option>
    </select>    
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: like @adeneo's solution, text is only visible when scolling down with firefox.

Comment: @michltm Updated with a _dirty trick_ as FF obviously doesn't report back the correct color from an option element

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Jsfiddle**

[Option selected text color](https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/281/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $("select").on("change", function(){
    $("select option").css("color", "blue");
    $(this).find("option:selected").css("color", "red");
  })
})
```

`$("select option").css("color", "blue");`

This line reset the previous color.

`$(this).find("option:selected").css("color", "red");`

This is the line for color the selected option of the selectbox.